# Fundamental theorem of line integral for Lipschitz continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous, can we conclude that
$$ \int_{[0,1]} (y-x)^T \nabla f(\mu y + (1-\mu )x) \text{d}\mu = f(y) - f(x) $$
where $\int$ stands for Lebesgue integral?

Comment: I came across the following [paper](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/papers/grad-thm-for-lipschitz.pdf]).